# Zorn's Lemma - partial order, or preorder?

Tags: set-theory, relations, order-theory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) Zorn's Lemma says;

> *every partially ordered set containing upper bounds for every chain necessarily contains at least one maximal element.*

According to [Nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Zorn%27s+lemma) Zorn's Lemma says something slightly different;

> *Every preorder in which every sub-total order has an upper bound has a maximal element.*

Are these different?  Is the nlab version stronger than the other?

I can see how most of it corresponds;

- sub-total order $\mapsto$ chain.
- at least one maximal $\mapsto$ a maximal

but I have to conclude with its weaker *preorder* condition, the nlab version is a stronger theorem.  Is this correct?

Am I right in thinking that when there are multiple maximal elements, they might look like a cyclic set that fails antisymmtry such $a\preceq b\preceq c\preceq a$, and in this case every distinct element $a,b,$ and $c$ are maximal elements?

I'm unclear whether it can be the case that there are separate distinct maximal chains e.g. $a\preceq a$ and $b\preceq b$ which do not satisfy $a\preceq b$.

Comment: According to Dummit & Foote (I read Dummit) ''_If $A$ is a non-empty partially ordered set in which every chain has an upper bound then $A$ has a maximal element._" And also that Zorn's lemma is independent of the _Zermelo - Fraenkel Axioms of Set Theory_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no essential difference in the sense that one version is stronger than the other.

It is more a question of: one version of the lemma  is translated into another.

Double translations are neutral.

---

If $(P,\preceq)$ denotes a preorder then it induces on a natural way a partial order $(P',\leq)$.

Elements of $P'$ are equivalence classes wrt to relation:$$x\sim y\iff x\preceq y\wedge y\preceq x$$

Relation $[x]\leq[y]$ on $P'$ defined by $x\preceq y$ appears to be *well defined*.

A maximal element $[m]$ in $P'$ is actually a set of maximal elements in $P$ and for every $x,y\in[m]$ we have $x\preceq y\wedge y\preceq x$ (so yes, there is cycling there).

On the partial order we have the lemma of Zorn and "translating" it to the original preorder gives a formulation of the lemma for preorders (and vice versa).

IMV it is a good habit to connect any preorder that you meet at once with the partial order that is induced by it.

---

Edit:

Usually an element $m$ is defined to be maximal if: $$m\leq a\implies m=a\text{ for every }a$$

This works fine in partial orders but not in preorders.

A definition that works for both is:

$$m\text{ is maximal if }m\leq a\implies a\leq m\text{ for every }a$$

Comment: So just to be clear (say it back to you in my own words) if $\prec$ is a preorder on $X$ and I have $a\prec b\prec a$ then you recommend setting $a\sim b$ so that $\prec$ is a partial order on $X/{\sim}$?

Comment: Yes. That quotient gives you bright view on the original preorder. Actually it turns equivalence into equality. If you visualize (as far as possible) then it turns balls into points.

Comment: ok, one last push for more... suppose we have the nlab version *Every preorder in which every sub-total order has an upper bound has a maximal element.* and we have a cyclic chain $a\prec b\prec c\prec a$.  It means we have three "maximal elements", right - not one?

Comment: Yes. If you have that relation among $a,b,c$ and e.g. $a$ serves as maximal element then so do $b$ and $c$. Don't forget though that in the case of partial orders more than one maximal element is not excluded. If in that case $m_1$ and $m_2$ both serve as maximal element then $m_1$ and $m_2$ are not comparable.

Comment: Aha, that's what I was looking for, thank-you.  Let me try to say it back to you:  If we only have a preorder then multiple maximal elements might be comparable, but if we have a partial order then multiple maximal elements are necessarily not comparable. Are both those statements right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If $m,n$ are maximal elements in a partial order with $m\leq n$ then we need $m=n$.This because $m\neq n$ contradicts then that $m$ is maximal. That is different in a preorder.